# How to query range in Firebase database like (a >= 26 or a <= 3)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there an workaround to query in the range like `(a >= 26 OR a <= 3)`.
I tried something like

```
userRef.orderByChild("paybackDay").startAt(26).endAt(3)
```

but result only contains data with `paybackDay = 26`.

Comment: @NickA no it doesn't, anything between 3 and 26 is excluded

Comment: I meant OR,  values in the range (a > 3 AND a < 26) are not desired

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ... It's been a long morning apparently, I read it as a >= 3 OR a <= 26, must have got confused by the larger number coming first >.<

Comment: @NickA relatable :) anyway, putting an AND would have resulted in NO values at all, because you can't have a number that is both `<=3` and `>=26`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, I see that now, thanks for the reminder to get more coffee

Comment: A simple workaround I can think of is using two seperate queries and combining the results.

Comment: @AndréKool could you please elaborate, how to combine two queries?

Comment: No, not combining queries but combining the results from different queries. You have one query for the values <=3 and another query for values >=26.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the suggestion from  @André Kool, this solution worked for me. However do make sure that index in both queries must differ in order to avoid duplication in result. Thanks

```
userRef.orderByChild("paybackDay").startAt(26)
   .addValueEventListener(
       new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

              ArrayList<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
              for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  members.add(snapshot.getValue(Member.class));
              }

              ArrayList<Member> finalMembers = members;

              mDatabaseUtils.mMemberRef.orderByChild("paybackDay").endAt(3)
                  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                             for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                   finalMembers.add(snapshot.getValue(Member.class));   
                             }

                             // finalMembers is the resultant list.
                   }

                          @Override
                          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
       });`
```